# Issue finding info on get-process

Tags: powershell

When I do this:

```
help get-process
```

I get this:

```
Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
Get-Process                       Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Man… Gets the processes that are running on the local…
Get-Process                       Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Man… Gets the processes that are running on the local…
```

Why doesn't the help command work for get-process?  It works for other commands.

Comment: Im not getting that issue. Have you restart powershell?

Comment: you have two modules that contain that cmdlet. you need to find them, determine which is the newer one, and remove the older one.

Comment: Something like `Get-Command Get-Process | select DLL, Version` might help you work out where each cmdlet is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Try get-help command. Use -examples at end to get more info.

Get-Help -Name Get-Process